# How to remove table of symbol from a library in Python

Tags: c++, python-3.x

In shell, when I run `find . -type f -name '*.so*"' -exec strip {} \;`, the table of symbols are removed from the .so files.

How do I achieve the same thing in Python 3.+ ? I would like to do it in an o.s. independent manner, so that I could run the script on both Linux and Windows if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could technically just do

```py
cmd = "find /usr/lib -name '*.so' | xargs ls -l"
subprocess.run( ["/bin/bash","-c",cmd] )
```

or you can use pathlib

```py
from pathlib import Path
for path in Path('/usr').rglob('*.so'):
    print(path.absolute())
```

Produces

```
/usr/local/lib/libclang-cpp.so
/usr/local/lib/libluajit-5.1.so
/usr/local/lib/liblldb.so
/usr/local/lib/libluajit.so
/usr/local/lib/libbson-1.0.so
/usr/local/lib/liblldbIntelFeatures.so
/usr/local/lib/libLTO.so
/usr/local/lib/libmongoc-1.0.so
/usr/local/lib/libRemarks.so
...
```

Comment: Thanks, however, I'm wondering if its possible with native Python, as I want to be able to run the script on Windows. Maybe its not possible to do it, I don't know.